# Shopify Order Status

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

is it possible to change the whole order status system so that when a customer buys the order first get set on pending, then when a staff aproved it it goes to in progress and if not approved it refunds the money and deletes the order?

Thanks

I search online but didn´t found what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

It already exists, you may choose not to fulfill automatically an order when it's placed. For that, go to settings page, then checkout tabs and check what's on the image:

[image: Settings > Checkout]

Not fulfilled = pending.